# ChiliProject on Windows 7

Tags: ruby, windows, chiliproject

When I start server with -d prefix, it make error:

```
C:\ruby\chili>bundle exec ruby script/server -e production -p 3005 -d
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.14 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3005
C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/process/daemon.rb:4:in `fork': fork() function is unimplemented on this machine (NotImplementedError)
    from C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/process/daemon.rb:4:in `daemon'
    from C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/commands/server.rb:62
    from script/server:4:in `require'
    from script/server:4
```

Is possible run it as service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using FireDaemon (which makes any program running as windows service).